# camlp5: how to nest antiquotations

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

I am using camlp5 with the `MLast` module. I would like to know the syntax for antiquotations of nesting depth greater than 1. I'll explain with a mock example. Suppose I have

```
let f1 e = <:expr< 3 * $e$ >>
let f2 e = <:expr< $e$ + 1 >>
let f3 e = <:expr< $e$ / 2 >>
let f123 e = f3 (f2 (f1 e))
```

How can I define `f123` in one go? For only two parts I could do

```
let f12 e = <:expr< $<:expr< 3 * \$e\$ >>$ + 1 >>
```

Note the mandatory backslashes in the inner antiquotation. But for three parts? Neither of the following works:

```
let f123 e = <:expr< $<:expr< \$<:expr< 3* \$e\$ >>\$ + 1 >>$ / 2 >>
let f123 e = <:expr< $<:expr< \$<:expr< 3* \\$e\\$ >>\$ + 1 >>$ / 2 >>
let f123 e = <:expr< $<:expr< \$<:expr< 3* \\\$e\\\$ >>\$ + 1 >>$ / 2 >>
```

The respective error messages are:

```
Uncaught exception: Pcaml.Qerror ("expr", 1, _)
Uncaught exception: Pcaml.Qerror ("expr", 1, _)
Parse error: end of input expected after [expr] (in [expr_eoi])
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs.

(P.S. Of course I know that in this specific example I could omit the inner antiquotation/quotation pairs. That is beside the point; it is due to the oversimplification inherent in the mock example.)

Comment: Is it ocamlp4 (tag) or ocamlp5 (title)?

Comment: @coredump: It is camlp5. There is no tag for camlp5 yet and camlp5 is a fork of camlp4: AFAIUI, at some point the maintainers of camlp4 decided to do a complete (and not backwards-compatible) overhaul and camlp5 is a continuation of the original project. Hence I assumed that camp4 is OK as a tag.